# Installing python module on mac osx with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip, shopify, bash

I have what seems to be a standard question about installing Python modules on OS X. The solutions I've read and tried are not working.

Basic situation:
I have a very fresh mac with basically, up to now, no additional packages installed. I installed Python 2.7 and pip, and now I'm trying to get the ShopifyAPI module for Python to work. (I decided to do a clean install of python so that I would not interfere with the pre-installed osx version.)

---

Steps taken:

1. Installed `python-2.7.9-macosx10.6.pkg`. I can see the install under my Applications directory.
2. Ran `Update Shell Profile.command` by clicking on it through Finder.
3. Ran `python get-pip.py` in terminal
4. Installed the Shopify API with `python -m pip install ShopifyAPI` in terminal
5. `python testshop` throws error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testshop.py", line 1, in <module>
       import shopify
   ImportError: No module named shopify_api
   ```

---

Other outcomes:

1. `python` reports `Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46)`
2. My .bash_profile is

   ```
   #Setting PATH for Python 2.7
   #The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
   PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
   export PATH
   ```
3. The contents of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` is the following:

   ```
   drwxrwxr-x  35 root      admin   1190 Feb 13 17:36 .
   drwxrwxr-x  10 root      admin    340 Feb 13 07:27 ..
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      6 Feb 13 07:27 2to3 -> 2to3-2
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      8 Feb 13 07:27 2to3-2 -> 2to3-2.7
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin    140 Dec 10 10:13 2to3-2.7
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin    309 Feb 13 07:27 easy_install
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin    309 Feb 13 07:27 easy_install-2.7
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      5 Feb 13 07:27 idle -> idle2
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      7 Feb 13 07:27 idle2 -> idle2.7
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin    138 Dec 10 10:13 idle2.7
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 me        admin    281 Feb 13 08:48 pip
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 me        admin    281 Feb 13 08:48 pip2
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 me        admin    281 Feb 13 08:48 pip2.7
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      6 Feb 13 07:27 pydoc -> pydoc2
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      8 Feb 13 07:27 pydoc2 -> pydoc2.7
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin    123 Dec 10 10:13 pydoc2.7
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      7 Feb 13 07:27 python -> python2
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     10 Feb 13 07:27 python-32 -> python2-32
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     14 Feb 13 07:27 python-config -> python2-config
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      9 Feb 13 07:27 python2 -> python2.7
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     12 Feb 13 07:27 python2-32 -> python2.7-32
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     16 Feb 13 07:27 python2-config -> python2.7-config
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin  25624 Dec 10 10:13 python2.7
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin  13928 Dec 10 10:13 python2.7-32
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin   1726 Dec 10 10:13 python2.7-config
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      8 Feb 13 07:27 pythonw -> pythonw2
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     11 Feb 13 07:27 pythonw-32 -> pythonw2-32
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     10 Feb 13 07:27 pythonw2 -> pythonw2.7
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     13 Feb 13 07:27 pythonw2-32 -> pythonw2.7-32
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin  25624 Dec 10 10:13 pythonw2.7
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin  13928 Dec 10 10:13 pythonw2.7-32
   -rwxr-xr-x   1 me        admin   8751 Feb 13 08:50 shopify_api.py
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin      9 Feb 13 07:27 smtpd.py -> smtpd2.py
   -rwxrwxr-x   1 root      admin  18586 Dec 10 10:13 smtpd2.7.py
   lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     11 Feb 13 07:27 smtpd2.py -> smtpd2.7.py
   ```

---

The bash profile seems odd to me and I believe only the Update Shell Profile.command would have changed it. The `.bash_profile.pysave` that the `.bash_profile` mentions doesn't exist in `~`.

Other things I've tried and have received the same import error from python:

1. Running `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python2.7 testshop`
2. Creating and setting PYTHONPATH in the bash_profile as `"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin"` and running `python testshop`

Comment: It is not rceommended to install any Python modules on the system-wide Python installation. I suggest you create a virtualenv for your development projects  and follow Python package installation tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by system-wide. Do you mean the Apple-installed Python version? I'm aware of the virutalenv and may end up using it but I followed the steps that are basically outlined at https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html, which may no mention of the virtual env. Is there something that I did wrong specifically in the "Step taken" I outlined in my question? I took those steps so that I would avoid interfering with the Apple-installed version.

Comment: Yes. You should not try to install any Python packages over Apple-provided Python. Python 2 documentations do not mention virtualenv because they date time before it. Please refer to packaging.python.org.

Comment: Mikko,  as shown, my installation created a new seperate Python directory and the api was imported there and not the Apple-version. Please correct me with details if I am wrong on this point.

Comment: I suggest just stick with the virtualenv. It is very difficult to give pointers what could go wrong, as hundreds of things can go wrong with custom setups, and it is much more cost effective, in term of work hours, to create virtualenv environment and use it, because it is pretty much guaranteed to work.

Comment: Mikko, you've given me zero insight in understanding why the use of pip and an alternative Python installation did not work. You are simply promoting virtual env as a alternative solution without helping me fix a method that worked apparently well enough before virtual env came around.

Comment: That's why it is a comment, not an answer. If I knew answer for your problem I would leave it here as an answer. What I promote here is a Python community best practice how to install packages, so that there would be less need to troubleshoot random Python package installation problems.

Comment: Systemwide package installation is justified IMO if a package is used by several users in several projects on the same machine. If `N` users with on average `M` projects that rely on, say, NumPy, install `N*M` virtual environments with NumPy, then the machine will have `N*M` NumPy instances, taking up quite some storage space. Having said that, packages used in only one (or a few) projects obviously belong in virtualenvs. There seems to be no universal solution, pick the one that suits you best (as always).